# Node.js Express Angular app not affected by file updates

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I have a very simple Node.js/express app that I built using the tutorial by Traversy Media here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uONz0lEWft0

During the build process, I would make updates to the .ts and .HTML files in the components directory and the web app would reflect the changes. I've since uploaded the project to github and cloned it to a new MEAN stack on Ubuntu. Now, when I make changes to the component files and the angular-src directory, the app is totally unaffected and continues to run as if no changes were made to any of the files.

I've tried to start and restart Node.js but I feel like the app is compiled or "built" now and is no longer referencing my files.

How do I get back to the point where I can further develop this app?

github link: https://github.com/negativepitch/Mean-LoginApp

Answer (score 0):

First don't upload node_modules.That's why you have package.json ;)
Then, have you tried to execute npm install ?

Comment: Thank you for the tip, Akim. I've removed the node_modules directory. Also, I have run the npm install but still get the same results. I believe the app is running from the "public" folder where I notice that all my modules have been compiled into the "main.bundle.js" file. Is there a way to make the app run from the modules directory again?